# How can I sit in on a stream without getting in the way, while capturing and testing it?

Tags: shell, shell-script, io-redirection

How can I test whether a command's output is an empty string while not 
 interfering with buffering?  Example:

```
command | ???
if [ $? = 0 ] && [ -n "$output_from_command"]; then
   ...
```

I want the output from the code above to be the same as when running `command`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tee` command, which accepts input from stdin and writes the output to stdout plus a file.

```
command | (umask 077; exec tee "/tmp/out.$$")
```

Then you can `test -s "/tmp/out.$$"` to see whether it is of zero length or not. (Note that `$$` expands to the current pid, which helps avoid similar processes overwriting one another. You may prefer using `mktemp` where available to avoid issues where an attacker would guess the file name and create a symlink in its place)

Comment: I think I can tee to `/dev/tty` and avoid the temp file: `out=$(echo 'hi'|tee /dev/tty)`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT="$(echo "foo")"  # replace 'echo "foo"' with your command

if [[ -z "$OUTPUT" ]]; then
   echo "No output."
else
   echo "$OUTPUT"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but has the disadvantage that lines are printed all at once, whereas command may print lines at a certain rate.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to see the output in real time, `tee` is probably your best bet.

Comment: That assumes no NUL character in the output, that the output is not `-n` or `-nene`... and it will remove the trailing newlines characters (and add one back).

Answer (score 1):

```
if the-command | grep '^'; then
  echo the-command output was not empty
fi
```

(note that the behaviour will vary across `grep` implementations if the output of `the-command` is not text (contains NUL characters, doesn't end in a newline character or has abnormally long lines).

To also check the exit status of `the-command`, you could use the `pipefail` option available in a number of shells (bash, ksh93, zsh, yash, mksh at least):

```
if (set -o pipefail; the-command | grep '^'); then
  echo the-command was successful and its output was not empty
fi
```

To work with non-text data, you can replace `grep '^'` with:

```
PERLIO=:unix perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\65536} END{exit!$.}'
```

Note that some commands change their outputting behaviour when their stdout is not a terminal device (here changed to a pipe), so that could still have an effect on the output.